# FLEX: Размер дочерних элементов flex-wrap: wrap с 100% заполнением контейнера

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть контейнер в котором 9 элементов.
Мне нужно расположить их:

1. По 4 в каждой строке
2. Элементы во всю ширину колонки
3. Строка с нечетным количеством имеет 3 элемента равной ширины

```css
    ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    }
    li {
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 23%;
    border: 1px solid;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(4n) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Делал таким образом, но столкнулся с тем, что в крайней строке элементы тоже растягиваются.
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/JIvFKgSAgNxYJw

**Каким образом мне сделать, чтобы все дочерние были единой ширины? Например 9 (10,11) такого же размера как и остальные, но при этом заполняли 100% пространства.**
Голову уже сломал. Пробовал фикс ширину задавать, но у каждой колонки с правой стороны оставался зазор, а width: 23.9999% не очень красиво будет.

UPD: Ответ нашел в width:calc( 100%  / 4 );

Answer (score 0):

Так имеете ввиду?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 23%;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
ul li:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Даа. А вот теперь как бы совместить это с

flex-grow: 1;

Чтобы 9-й элемент не растягивался на 100%. Например в случае если у меня 6,7,8 элементов в строке будет.

Comment: не понятно, можете показать рисунок как нужно

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ieUJGT-dINEBnA

Я сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что крайний элемент не идет в 100%, решал это с помощью flex-grow: 1;, но крайняя строка выглядит так
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/R6IDvZNyUAosXQ

Comment: изменил ответ свой в css. К последнему элементу добавляйте flex-grow: 1;

Answer (score 0):

> Строка с нечетным количеством имеет 3 элемента равной ширины,

думаю нужно добавить `flex-grow: 1;` и изменить на `flex: 0 0 23%;`  для `li`.
И `box-sizing: border-box;` желательно добавить для `ul`

Будет так

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 23%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Согласен.
Суть вопроса в том, чтобы 9,10,11 были такого же размера как будто их 4 в строке (width как у 1-8 элементов)

Comment: Так так и есть сейчас, последний ряд 3 блока равной ширины, или должно быть по другому?

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью width:calc( 100%  / 3 );

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел в width:calc( 100% / 4 );